# Authority vs Authorization, are they the same?

Tags: statutory-construction

This may be more of a grammatical/english question, but is there likely to be any dispute that there is a difference between the two words?

Compare:

Eg.1  Words giving authority to a group authorize a majority of the group to act.

Eg.2  Words authorizing a group to act authorize a majority of the group to act.

The point of dispute rests in the fact that sometimes a group is given permission to do certain acts and at other times they are required to do certain acts.  The disputed outcome is whether or not a majority of the group can act in either interpretation.

Comment: The words are different, but related.  If you can provide a more meaningful context for your question, you're more likely to get a helpful answer.  *Why* would anyone assert that the words are the same or different?  Why are you interested in the difference or lack thereof?

Comment: Is the group an entity that can undertake official acts by majority vote?

Comment: @phoog - Thats the million dollar question.

Comment: The answer to the question about the nature of the group is unlikely to be found in the definition of the words "authority" and "authorization."  This is all very abstract.  Some more detail would be very helpful.

Comment: my question is about the nature of the words authority and authorization.  to tell you more would be to ask for legal advice, which I do not want to do.  i'll form my own conclusions based on the possible answer to this question

Comment: The meaning of authority and authorization are independent of the kind of person or entity to whom they are granted, and can be found in a dictionary.  If the application of the definition in a particular context raises some question, it is necessary to discuss that context.  Finally, it is possible too ask questions relating to a specific situation without that being a request for advice about that situation. Maybe if you're lucky, someone more able than I to address your question without any specifics ell come along.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The definitions (in context) are:

**giving**: cause or allow (someone or something) to have (something, especially something abstract)

**authority**: the power or right to give orders, make decisions, and enforce obedience

So:

**giving authority**: cause or allow (someone or something) to have the power or right to give orders, make decisions, and enforce obedience

And

**authorize**: give official permission for or approval to (an undertaking or agent)

They are functionally equivalent.